# xpath works in selenium recording, but does not run in Eclipse

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I am trying to run a test in Eclipse that was previously recorded in Selenium. I was able to get it to run in Selenium by using an XPath. However, in Eclipse I get an NoSuchElement error. I am trying to click on a tab on the page, the problem is that the tabs are not listed as buttons, but they are actually in a table. Here is the line that I have in place now.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@onclick=\"parent.frames.contentFrame.location='/messaging/maintfList.jsp?clearUIPath=true&uiPathLabel=Forms'\"])")).click();
```

Here is what I am shown when I inspect the element. All of the tabs are listed as menu-normal, the only difference is in the pathlabel.

```
div class="menu-normal" onclick="parent.frames.contentFrame.location='/messaging/maintfList.jsp?clearUIPath=true&uiPathLabel=Forms'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[onclick='parent.frames.contentFrame.location='/messaging/maintfList.jsp?clearUIPath=true&uiPathLabel=Forms']")).click();
```

escaping anything that needs it in java.

xpath is a very inefficient way to find things, and there is almost always a better way of doing it. CssSelector in this case can find what you are looking for.

Edit: I've had a look into Java documentation, try this line instead

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[onclick=\"parent.frames.contentFrame.location='/messaging/maintfList.jsp?clearUIPath=true&uiPathLabel=Forms'\"]")).click();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error showing it as an invalid or illegal string when I inserted your line. I tried to add a few different things to get it to work, but no luck. I'm pretty new with this. Anything else I should look into or try?

Comment: I don't know java (I'm a c# developer) but I assume something needs to be escaped in the string. Try putting a backslash before the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='menu-normal'][2]")).click();
```

> //here [2] is the position number of menu-normal on the page. Let us
>   assume there are 4 tabs with same class and you want to click on 2nd
>   one then you can use above code.

If it was not helpful, please share your html code.

Comment: It looks like the div is inside of a .jsp file that is loaded in on the main html. Could this be where the link breaks when I try to select it with driver.findElement?

Comment: This is the code inside of a form tag as well. 
<td><div class=menu-normal onClick="parent.frames.contentFrame.location='/messaging/maintfList.jsp?clearUIPath=true&uiPathLabel=Forms'">Forms</div></td>